# Countdown timer using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, components, react-hooks

So the timer works. If I hard code `this.state` with a specific countdown number, the timer begins counting down once the page loads. I want the clock to start counting down on a button click and have a function which changes the `null` of the `state` to a randomly generated number. I am a bit new to React. I am know that `useState()` only sets the initial value but if I am using a click event, how do I reset `useState()`? I have been trying to use `setCountdown(ranNum)` but it crashes my app. I am sure the answer is obvious but I am just not finding it.

If I didnt provide enough code, please let me know. I didn't want to post the whole shebang.

here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const Timer = ({ranNum, timerComplete}) => {
    const [ countDown, setCountdown ] = useState(ranNum)
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            countDown - 1 < 0 ? timerComplete() : setCountdown(countDown - 1)
        }, 1000)
    }, [countDown, timerComplete])
    return ( <p >Countdown: <span>{ countDown }</span> </p> )
}
```

```
  handleClick(){
    let newRanNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    this.generateStateInputs(newRanNum)
    let current = this.state.currentImg;
    let next = ++current % images.length;
    this.setState({
      currentImg: next,
      ranNum: newRanNum
    })
  }

 <Timer ranNum={this.state.ranNum} timerComplete={() => this.handleComplete()} />
 <Button onClick={this.handleClick}  name='Generate Inputs' />
 <DisplayCount name='Word Count: ' count={this.state.ranNum} />
```

Answer (score 6):

You should store `countDown` in the parent component and pass it to the child component. In the parent component, you should use a variable to trigger when to start `Timer`.
You can try this:

```js
import React from "react";

export default function Timer() {
  const [initialTime, setInitialTime] = React.useState(0);
  const [startTimer, setStartTimer] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    setInitialTime(5);
    setStartTimer(true);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (initialTime > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("startTime, ", initialTime);
        setInitialTime(initialTime - 1);
      }, 1000);
    }

    if (initialTime === 0 && startTimer) {
      console.log("done");
      setStartTimer(false);
    }
  }, [initialTime, startTimer]);

  return (
    <div>
      <buttononClick={handleOnClick}>
        Start
      </button>
      <Timer initialTime={initialTime} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Timer = ({ initialTime }) => {
  return <div>CountDown: {initialTime}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`useState` sets the initial value just like you said, but in your case I don't think you want to store the `countDown` in the `Timer`. The reason for it is that `ranNum` is `undefined` when you start the application, and gets passed down to the `Timer` as undefined. When `Timer` mounts, `useEffect` will be triggered with the value `undefined` which is something you don't want since it will trigger the `setTimeout`. I believe that you can store `countDown` in the parent of the `Timer`, start the timeout when the button is clicked from the parent and send the `countDown` value to the `Timer` as a prop which would make the component way easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple implementation using hooks and setInterval

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
import './styles.css'

const STATUS = {
  STARTED: 'Started',
  STOPPED: 'Stopped',
}

export default function CountdownApp() {
  const [secondsRemaining, setSecondsRemaining] = useState(getRandomNum())
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(STATUS.STOPPED)

  const handleStart = () => {
    setStatus(STATUS.STARTED)
  }
  const handleStop = () => {
    setStatus(STATUS.STOPPED)
  }
  const handleRandom = () => {
    setStatus(STATUS.STOPPED)
    setSecondsRemaining(getRandomNum())
  }
  useInterval(
    () => {
      if (secondsRemaining > 0) {
        setSecondsRemaining(secondsRemaining - 1)
      } else {
        setStatus(STATUS.STOPPED)
      }
    },
    status === STATUS.STARTED ? 1000 : null,
    // passing null stops the interval
  )
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React Countdown Demo</h1>
      <button onClick={handleStart} type="button">
        Start
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleStop} type="button">
        Stop
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleRandom} type="button">
        Random
      </button>
      <div style={{padding: 20}}>{secondsRemaining}</div>
      <div>Status: {status}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

function getRandomNum() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
}

// source: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef()

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback
  }, [callback])

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current()
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay)
      return () => clearInterval(id)
    }
  }, [delay])
}
```

Here is a link to a codesandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-countdown-demo-random-c9dm8?file=/src/App.js